# match these values except for zero

Tags: regex

i have the following regex expression `^(([0-9]{1,2})|100|888|777|999)$`

this allows someone to enter the digits: 0-99, 100, 888, 777, 999

I now have to alter the expression to allow: 1-99, 100, 888, 777, 999 (essentially ZERO is not allowed now)

I thought of doing `^(!0|([0-9]{1,2})|100|888|777|999)$` ... but this of course won't work because that would be like saying "if it isn't zero, we are fine"

Any advice?

Comment: Did you try [1-9]{1,2} instead of [0-9]{1,2}?

Comment: @MarshallConover That won't work because it won't match any 2 digit number with a 0 in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try splitting off the cases for one digit vs two digit numbers:

`^([0-9]|([1-9][0-9])|100|888|777|999)$`

And then remove 0:

`^([1-9]|([1-9][0-9])|100|888|777|999)$`

Now that you have that, there's an obvious way to simplify it:

`^(([1-9][0-9]?)|100|888|777|999)$`

So, twain249, if you want to read in numbers with excessive zeroes at the front, but you won't want the match to include them:

`^0*(([1-9][0-9]?)|100|888|777|999)$`

Comment: I don't know if he wants to eliminate numbers like `02` but it's pretty easy to modify your regex to handle that.

Comment: thanks for showing me your thought process... waiting for the ability to mark this as the answer :P

Comment: @twain249 I didnt think of that issue, but here it is for others
`^(([0-9][1-9]{1})|([1-9][0-9]?)|100|888|777|999)$`

Answer (score 1):

This should achieve what you want:

```
^(([1-9][0-9]?)|100|888|777|999)$
```

Answer (score 1):

^([1-9][0-9]?)|100|888|777|999$